# Is it possible to install android wear apps on android smartphone?

Tags: stock-android, android-wear

I'm an Android developer and recently I've started to develop apps to Android Wear. The problem is that I don't have an Android watch and the emulator is too slow.

Does someone knows if there is a way to install Android Wear apps on an android smartphone or install the android wear os on android smartphone

Comment: I think till now there is no such way to test Android wear app in mobiles.

Comment: I use the Android Studio in-built emulator and there is no lag whatsoever, try configuring the VM to maxed out settings.